# Set type for fromarray() in opencv for python

Tags: python, opencv, types

I am using Python 2.7 and opencv 2.1.

I have a numpy array and I want to convert it to an opencv matrix of type "cv.CV_32FC1".
How can I set the type ?

"CreateMat()" allows for explicit type setting but "fromarray()" doesnt.
If I just apply fromarray on a float array the type check fails (one of the next modules performs a specific type check for CV_32FC1)

thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
dest = cv.createMat(r, c, cv.CV_32FC1)
src = cv.fromarray(your_np_array)
cv.Convert(src, dest)
```

where your numpy array has `r` rows and `c` columns.