# OpenCV - Create multichannel Mat from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, opencv, numpy

Given a numpy array like the one below, can you convert it to a multi-channel cv mat, collapsing the data into a single column?

```
arr = [[x1, y1],
       [x2, y2],  
       [x3, y3]]

arr = np.array(arr, dtype='f4')

mat = cv.fromarray(arr)
```

Done this way, the resulting mat has 3 rows and 2 single-channel columns (the mat is of type 32FC1). I need the resulting mat to have 3 rows and a single 2-channel column (specifically, to be of type 32FC2).

Comment: Does this thread helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535715/set-type-for-fromarray-in-opencv-for-python

Comment: Unfortunately no :( Attempting to use cv.Convert gives the following error: cv2.error: src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels(). Looks like you can't convert between mats with different numbers of channels.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.array()` on an existing array to create an array that will convert to an  OpenCV Mat with additional channels:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype='float32')
a = np.array([a])
```

Will convert to Mat of type CV_32FC2 (two channels) under `cv.fromarray`

[Source](http://answers.opencv.org/question/252/cv2perspectivetransform-with-python/?comment=65919#comment-65919)